# Who starts a program to run?

Tags: linux, shell, kernel, process, ram

Who starts a program to run on RAM? Is it Kernel?

Suppose I hit 'ls' command in linux, I know it is running on RAM processed by CPU-Core and make sys-call (to Kernel) whenever necessary and flush the o/p using syscall. But who really makes the 'ls' to run on a RAM?

Comment: What do you mean by "run on a RAM"? As opposed to running elsewhere? As far as I can see, it was you that caused the `ls` program to run by typing `ls` in a terminal.

Comment: One for the philosophers: "Proximate and ultimate causation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `ls` in a terminal, the shell that's running in that terminal (maybe bash, or zsh, etc.) will call a syscall telling the kernel to fork its process. It then tells the kernel to replace the process image of the new process to the `ls` program, with the `execve` syscall. This will load the code of the `ls` program from the disk into ram.

So if you mean what program causes the program to be run, it's the shell.